# Connecting oracle client installed on windows 10 to Oracle server installed on Virtual Box Windows 10

Tags: oracle, virtualbox

I have below setup:

My machine - Windows 10 with Virual Box and Oracle 12c client
On Virtual Box - Windows 10 with Oracle 12c Server

I need to connect to virtual box - oracle from my machine using sqlplus or any IDE.

I have tried Host Only adapter but I am not able to connect.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please detail what is not working with error messages: ping from host to guest ? sqlplus from host to guest ? Oracle listener configuration on guest ? something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the ip address of the hostonly adapter, on the Windows host?  You can check that with the command 'ipconfig' and look for the entry 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network'.

```
C:\Users\estevens\Documents>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e172:fa54:d3d6:9712%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Then, the network interface on the vm guest needs to be configured with a ***fixed*** ip address in the same subnet.  In the above example, the host adapter is at 192.168.56.1  so the vm guest could be anything else in the 192.168.56.*  (except for .1, as that is already taken).  With that configuration, you can treat the vm just like any remote server in the data center.

I've written more about it here: https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/configure-the-virtualbox-network-2/

-- Error correction 19-May-2020: discovered that I had a typo in one of the IP addresses used in the above discussion.  Corrected.